# Flutter does not fetch all Data

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to be short.
First i had a App where you can save a place with one image, and i can fetch it.
But now i tought well it would be better if you have the choice to upload two or three images.

I updated my code, but know when i create a new entry with one or two images, they disappear when i reload the app, only the one with 3 images are showing.

i tried it with 3 fetches, and a future wait, but that not work

now some code, i hope someone can help me, and i hope thats enough code

Thanks much.

Code with the adding screen:

```
class AddPlacesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routName = '/add-place';

  @override
  _AddPlacesScreenState createState() => _AddPlacesScreenState();
}

class _AddPlacesScreenState extends State<AddPlacesScreen> {
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  //Controller um das Titel zu "Kontrollieren"
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _pickedLocation = TextEditingController();
  final _pickedDescription = TextEditingController();
  final _pickedDuration = TextEditingController();

  // Variabeln für spätere Änderungen, mehr Bilder und Maps
  final _pickedLatitude = "1";
  final _pickedLongitude = "1";
  final _pickedAddress = "noAddressAvailable";

//_selectImage muss dann unten ImageInput übergeben werden und im WIdget definieren
  File _pickedImage;
  File _pickedImage2;
  File _pickedImage3;

  //PlaceLocation _pickedLocation;

  void _selectImage(File pickedImage) {
    //_pickedImage = pickedImage;
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = pickedImage;
    });
  }

  void _selectImage2(File pickedImage2) {
    //_pickedImage2 = pickedImage;
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage2 = pickedImage2;
    });
  }

  void _selectImage3(File pickedImage3) {
    _pickedImage3 = pickedImage3;
  }
  // void _selectPlace(double lat, double lng) {
  //  _pickedLocation = PlaceLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng);
  // }

//------------ TODOO FEHLERMELDUNG EINBAUEN UND DATUM ALS PFLICHTFELD ------------------------------
//_pickedImage == null || _pickedLocation == null

// set up the AlertDialog
  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Hoppala...'),
              content: Text(message),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'))
              ],
            ));
  }

  void _savePlace() {
    if (_titleController.text.isEmpty) {
      var errorMessage = 'Bitte gib einen Titel ein';
      return _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
    if (_pickedLocation.text.isEmpty) {
      var errorMessage = 'Bitte gib einen Ort ein';
      return _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
    if (_selectedDate == null) {
      var errorMessage = 'Bitte gib ein Datum ein';
      return _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
    if (_pickedImage == null) {
      var errorMessage = 'Bitte wähle mindestens ein Bild aus';
      return _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }

    //add place ausführen über provider
    Provider.of<GreatPlaces>(context, listen: false).addPlace(
      _titleController.text,
      _pickedImage,
      _pickedImage2,
      _pickedImage3,
      DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(_selectedDate),
      _pickedLocation.text,
      _pickedDescription.text,
      _pickedDuration.text,
      _pickedLatitude,
      _pickedLongitude,
      _pickedAddress,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    print(_pickedImage);
    print(_pickedImage2);
    print(_pickedImage3);
  }

  void _presentdatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      // muss gesetzt werden sonst wird die Form / Widget nicht aktualisiert
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Date Time beim öffnen soll die aktuelle Zeit bei mspeichern angezeigt werden
    //  final timeCreate = new DateTime.now();
    //  String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(timeCreate);
    // print(formattedDate);

    //bei ganzer Seite ein Scaffold
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Füge deine Wanderung hinzu'),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: <Color>[
                Colors.green[200],
                Colors.brown[300],
              ])),
        ),
      ),
      //Body mit Column da -> Spalte da wir sachen übereinander sind also von oben nach unten
      body: Column(
        //Text und Button werden getrennt oben und unten
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween <---- mit Expanded wird das nicht mehr benötigt
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          //Textfelder untereinander mit einem Expanded einfügen
          //Column warp mit widget dann Padding dann Padding wrappen mit SingleCHildScrollView in die Column kommen dann die Textfelder
          Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Titel'),
                    controller: _titleController,
                    // hier erweitern mit valdiation etc...
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Ort'),
                    controller: _pickedLocation,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  //Sizedbox mit 10 Pixel für eine nkleinen Abstand
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  //Widget erstellt für Container und Flatbutton in image_input.dart

                  _pickedImage == null
                      ? ImageInput(_selectImage)
                      : _pickedImage2 == null
                          ? ImageInput2(_selectImage2)
                          : ImageInput3(_selectImage3),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),

                  // ------- MAPS BOX AKTUELLER STANDOIRT UND STANDORT AUSWÄHLEN = LocationInput() aktuell nicht benötigt deshalb auskommentiert -----------
                  //location_input.dart
                  //LocationInput()
                  // ------ NEU Memo Feld --------
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Beschreibung',
                        hintText: "Kurze Beschreibung der Wanderung"),
                    controller: _pickedDescription,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Dauer',
                        hintText: "z.B. 3.5",
                        counterText: "",
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(1)),
                    controller: _pickedDuration,
                    maxLength: 5,
                  ),
                  //----------------- Datetime Picker --------------------
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            _selectedDate == null
                                ? 'Kein Datum ausgewählt!'
                                : ' Gewähltes Datum: ${DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(_selectedDate)}',
                          ),
                        ),
                        // WIdget ist in adaptive flat button, und übergabe erfolgt dann in ()
                        AdaptiveFlatButton(
                            'Datum auswählen', _presentdatePicker)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: Text('Berg Hinzufügen'),
            onPressed: _savePlace,
            elevation: 0,
            //Der button ist ganz unten an der Kante
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code with where all places should be:

```
class PlacesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routName = '/place-list';
  @override
  _PlacesListScreenState createState() => _PlacesListScreenState();
}

class _PlacesListScreenState extends State<PlacesListScreen> {
  var _isDeleted = false;

  //@override
  //void setState(fn) {
  //if (_isDeleted == true) {
  //print("ok ist jetzt drin");
  //_isDeleted = false;
  //}
  // super.setState(fn);
  //}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: //Platform.isIOS
            //? CupertinoNavigationBar(
            //  middle: Text('Berg-Tagebuch'),
            //  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            //  onPressed: () {
            //  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddPlacesScreen.routName);
            // }),
            //)
            // : AppBar(
            AppBar(
          title: Text('Berg-Tagebuch'),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: <Color>[
                  Colors.green[200],
                  Colors.brown[300],
                ])),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                //zum neuen Screen navigieren
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddPlacesScreen.routName);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),

        //wenn sich was ändert im GreatPlaces dann soll die Liste sich hier aktualiseren
        body: FutureBuilder(
          //aus great_places.dart hole ich mir die fetch Methode die ich erstellt habe
          //Zusätzlich 2 weitere erstellt um 2 images und mit 3 images zu laden
          future: Future.wait([
            Provider.of<GreatPlaces>(context, listen: false)
                .fetchAndSetPlaces(),
            Provider.of<GreatPlaces>(context, listen: false)
                .fetchAndSetPlaces2(),
            Provider.of<GreatPlaces>(context, listen: false)
                .fetchAndSetPlaces3()
          ]),

          builder: (ctx, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.waiting
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
                  child: Center(
                    child: const Text(
                        'Noch keine Wanderungen hinzugefügt, fang jetzt an !'),
                  ),
                  builder: (ctx, greatPlaces, ch) => greatPlaces.items.length <=
                          0
                      ? ch
                      : //ListView.separator -----> mit Linien was ist besser ?
                      ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: greatPlaces.items.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            ),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                    FileImage(greatPlaces.items[index].image),
                              ),
                              title: Text(greatPlaces.items[index].title),
                              subtitle:
                                  Text(greatPlaces.items[index].createTime),
                              //   On Tap öffnet dann die Details Seite
                              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                  PlaceDetailScreen.routName,
                                  arguments: greatPlaces.items[index].id),
                              trailing: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    //Button um in den bearbeitungsmodus zu wechseln
                                    IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                        onPressed: () =>
                                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                              EditPlacesScreen.routName,
                                              arguments:
                                                  greatPlaces.items[index].id,
                                            ),
                                        color: Colors.cyan),
                                    IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        try {
                                          print(_isDeleted);
                                          return showDialog(
                                              context: context,
                                              barrierDismissible: true,
                                              builder: (param) {
                                                return AlertDialog(
                                                  actions: [
                                                    FlatButton(
                                                      onPressed: () =>
                                                          Navigator.pop(
                                                              context),
                                                      child: Text("Abbruch"),
                                                      color: Colors.green[100],
                                                    ),
                                                    FlatButton(
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        DBHelper.delete(
                                                            greatPlaces
                                                                .items[index]
                                                                .id);
                                                        //set state damit löschen aktualisiert wird
                                                        setState(() {});

                                                        Scaffold.of(ctx)
                                                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                                content: Text(
                                                                    "Die Wanderung wurde entfernt")));
                                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                                      },
                                                      child: Text("Löschen"),
                                                      color: Colors.red[200],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                  title: Text(
                                                      "Wanderung wirklich löschen ?"),
                                                );
                                              });
                                        } catch (error) {
                                          //Hinweis geben das löschen fehlgeschlagen ist über snackbar
                                          //  scaffold.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                          //   content: Text(
                                          // 'Löschen Fehlgeschlagen !!',
                                          // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          // )));
                                        }
                                      },
                                      color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          // separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                          //   color: Colors.black,
                          // ),
                        ),
                ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And the one where with the methods:

```
class GreatPlaces with ChangeNotifier {
  //To set Creation Time
  static DateTime actualTime = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(actualTime);

  List<Place> _items = [];

  List<Place> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  //Information des gesamten places
  Place findById(String id) {
    return items.firstWhere((place) => place.id == id);
  }

  Future<void> addPlace(
    String pickedTitle,
    File pickedImage,
    File pickedImage2,
    File pickedImage3,
    String pickedDate,
    String pickedLocation,
    String pickedDescription,
    String pickedDuration,
    String pickedLatitude,
    String pickedLontitude,
    String pickedAdress,
    //PlaceLocation pickedLocation,
  ) async {
    //final address = await LocationHelper.getPlaceAddress(
    //  pickedLocation.latitude, pickedLocation.longitude);
    //   final updatedLocation = PlaceLocation(
    //    latitude: pickedLocation.latitude,
    //   longitude: pickedLocation.longitude,
    //    address: address);
    final newPlace = Place(
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      image: pickedImage,
      image2: pickedImage2,
      image3: pickedImage3,
      title: pickedTitle,
      createTime: pickedDate,
      place: pickedLocation,
      description: pickedDescription,
      duration: pickedDuration,
    );
    //location: null);
    _items.add(newPlace);
    notifyListeners();
    //übergabe 'wanderwege' so wie in db_helper definiert , Data ist von typ map
    DBHelper.insert('user_places', {
      'id': newPlace.id,
      'title': newPlace.title,
      'image': newPlace.image.path,
      'image2': newPlace.image2.path,
      'image3': newPlace.image3.path,
      'createTime': newPlace.createTime,
      'place': newPlace.place,
      'description': newPlace.description,
      'duration': newPlace.duration,
      'loc_lat': newPlace.latitude,
      'loc_lng': newPlace.longitude,
      'address': newPlace.address,
    });
  }

  //Die ganzen places aus der DB holen
  Future<void> fetchAndSetPlaces() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('user_places');
    _items = dataList
        .map((item) => Place(
              id: item['id'],
              title: item['title'],
              image: File(item['image']),
              createTime: item['createTime'],
              place: item['place'],
              description: item['description'],
              duration: item['duration'],
              latitude: null,
              longitude: null,
              address: null,
            ))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetPlaces2() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('user_places');
    _items = dataList
        .map((item) => Place(
              id: item['id'],
              title: item['title'],
              image: File(item['image']),
              image2: File(item['image2']),
              createTime: item['createTime'],
              place: item['place'],
              description: item['description'],
              duration: item['duration'],
              latitude: null,
              longitude: null,
              address: null,
            ))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetPlaces3() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('user_places');
    _items = dataList
        .map((item) => Place(
              id: item['id'],
              title: item['title'],
              image: File(item['image']),
              image2: File(item['image2']),
              image3: File(item['image3']),
              createTime: item['createTime'],
              place: item['place'],
              description: item['description'],
              duration: item['duration'],
              latitude: null,
              longitude: null,
              address: null,
            ))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, i had to add two new save method with one image and with two images.
then chekc how many images are uploaded and the right save method.
Know all places will be saved and showed